# Python3 [Jupyter] code is not showing data on graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, physics

I'm sure this question has been asked numerous times before but alas I cannot find the correct answer. I'm trying to plot really simple code however when it executes the final result is just an empty graph. Code below:

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl
import numpy as np

Q = 13.6
m_e = 9.11e-31
k = 8.6e-5
c = 3e8
eta = 4e-10

for T in np.arange(3000,4500):

    S = 3.84*eta*((k*T)/(m_e*c**2))**(3/2)*(Q/(k*T))
    X = (-1 + np.sqrt(1+(4*S)))/(2*S)

%matplotlib inline

mpl.plot(S, T)
mpl.show()
```

I realise that is the way with code it's probably a very trivial answer but I can't find the problem. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Did you want to call `mpl.plot(S, X)` actually?

Comment: I believe the question is asking for mpl.plot(X, T) but that still gives me nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything with the values you create in the for loop. Therefore, when you come to plot, you just have 1 value of `S` and `X` and `T`, therefore, your graph will be empty.

One way to fix this would be to append the values into a list which you can then pass to a call to `plot`:

```
Q = 13.6
m_e = 9.11e-31
k = 8.6e-5
c = 3e8
eta = 4e-10

S_list = []
X_list = []

for T in np.arange(3000,4500):

    S = 3.84*eta*((k*T)/(m_e*c**2))**(3/2)*(Q/(k*T))
    X = (-1 + np.sqrt(1+(4*S)))/(2*S)
    S_list.append(S)
    X_list.append(X)
```

I'm not sure if you actually want to plot the values of `S` against `T`, but if you do, then you would do something like:

```
mpl.plot(S_list, np.arange(3000,4500))
mpl.show()
```

Which gives something like:

[image]

**Edit:**

You don't actually need to do any loops here, `numpy` can handle the complete calculation:

```
T = np.arange(3000,4500)

S = 3.84*eta*((k*T)/(m_e*c**2))**(3/2)*(Q/(k*T))
X = (-1 + np.sqrt(1+(4*S)))/(2*S)

mpl.plot(S, T)
mpl.show()
```

Would give you the same figure

Comment: Thank you so much it works!

Comment: I think the `plot` can also be in the loop. Data-points would be drawn one-by-one, and no lists have to be accumulated. This is obviously, a design decision.

Answer (score 0):

S, X and T are all scalar. I am assuming you want to plot a vector against vector.

I think you are trying to do this:

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl
import numpy as np

Q = 13.6
m_e = 9.11e-31
k = 8.6e-5
c = 3e8
eta = 4e-10
S=[]
X=[]
for T in np.arange(3000,4500):
    tmp=3.84*eta*((k*T)/(m_e*c**2))**(3/2)*(Q/(k*T))
    S.append(tmp)
    X.append((-1 + np.sqrt(1+(4*tmp)))/(2*tmp))

%matplotlib inline

mpl.plot(S, X)
mpl.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl
import numpy as np

Q = 13.6
m_e = 9.11e-31
k = 8.6e-5
c = 3e8
eta = 4e-10
x=[]
t=[]
for T in np.arange(3000,4500):
    S = 3.84*eta*((k*T)/(m_e*c**2))**(3/2)*(Q/(k*T))
    X = (-1 + np.sqrt(1+(4*S)))/(2*S)
    x.append(X)
    t.append(T)

mpl.plot(x,t)
mpl.show()
```